Issue with MailChimp merge tag for URL
In the body of the MailChimp Confirmation thank you page I am using a merge variable to populate the href in an <a> tag. When the confirmation is visited by a user the URL is prefix by the page the user is on. eg:https://xxxxx.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com. I expect the URL to be https://test.com.
I've tried using both the source editor and also using the interface to add the merge variable in the <a> tag. Both will prefix the URL with the current page.
Here is the merge variable with logic:
*|IF:MERGE12|* <a href="*|URL:MERGE12|*" target="_blank">Click here to view the digital edition.</a> *|END:IF|*

Any ideas?

Apparently MailChimp want users to use the HTML: prefix when printing a full URL. The URL: prefix is for adding query arguments. Weird.
*|HTML:MERGE12|*

